# MSO CAF - Code Analysis Framework modifying Custom Rules?

Tags: development, sharepoint-online

I want to use the Micrsoft Online Code Analysis Framework for our Environment to check the Solutions. It is possible to modify the Custom Rules?

[Micrsoft Online Code Analysis Framework](https://caf.sharepoint.microsoftonline.com/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As the rules are compiled, they're just FxCop rules, you can't simply edit an xml file or something.

It is fairly easy to create your own FxCop rules, but there is very little documentation available. We had a few issues with the default MSOCAF rules, so I decompiled them using ,NET Reflector, fixed the issue, targeted them to FxCop 10 instead of 1.36 and they are now part of the automated build system in TFS.

See my blog for details:

- https://jessehouwing.net/search/?q=msocaf

The code, fixed for use in FxCop 10 is now available on Codeplex:

- https://github.com/jessehouwing/msocaf